# What was this Ziploc bag used for on an Apollo 14 moonwalk?

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program, environment, procedure, moonwalking

And how the heck would an astronaut have opened it with his gloves on? Is that bag likely to still be there in good condition, or would it have been broken down by radiation by now? Was it normal to just toss stuff that is no longer needed?

Upper right corner:

[image: image of retroreflector array and Ziploc bag on Moon surface]

from http://www.physics.ucsd.edu/~tmurphy/apollo/lrrr.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's not a [Ziploc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziploc) bag, but the retroreflector's dust cover. Here is a larger image of it removed:

[image]

And here's an image with the cover still attached to the retroreflector:

[image]

The clue is in the use of the red markings along the edges of the part in question, in spaceflight commonly used to indicate parts that need to be removed before use.

Both images from [Wikipedia on Apollo Lunar Surface Experiments Package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Lunar_Surface_Experiments_Package), credit [NASA History Office's Apollo Lunar Surface Journal](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/alsj/).

---

I wasn't able to find what the covers were made out of, but they appear to be clear PVC (Polyvinyl chloride). [PVC doesn't do terribly well in space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materials_for_use_in_vacuum#Materials_to_avoid) and exposure to UV radiation, thermal cycling and [sputtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sputtering) due to exposure to high energy radiation. Cover's current state is of course unknown, but it's a safe bet that it is by now nothing more than a thin layer of dust covered by more lunar surface dust moved around by photocharging, bombardment by hard and particle radiation,...

Answer (score 12):

To answer the last part of your question: yes, it was normal to throw away stuff that was no longer needed. On Apollo 11 alone, the [astronauts left behind more than 100 items](http://www.spiegel.de/international/zeitgeist/saving-moon-trash-urine-containers-space-boots-and-artifacts-aren-t-just-junk-argue-archaeologists-a-684221.html), including

> four urine containers, several airsickness bags, a Hasselblad camera, lunar overshoes and a complete moon-landing step.

The astronauts left behind as much as possible, to [save weight](http://gizmodo.com/this-hasselblad-camera-used-on-the-moon-just-sold-nea-1550241803) on the return trip. The Apollo spacecraft were on a very tight weight budget, and they had to allow for the ~ 380 kg of Moon samples they'd bring back over 6 mission.

Comment: Yeah, I knew they would leave as much weight behind as possible. For some reason, I always assumed that it would have been neatly stowed in the LM's descent stage though, not just strewn about on the surface.

Comment: *"several airsickness bags"* I hope they enjoyed the trip! Even without air. It wasn't tourism.

Comment: There was also that pesky little descent stage they left behind... :)

Comment: @DanRoss: There was no particular reason for the descent stage to have room to neatly stow discarded items.

Comment: The astronauts were working against the clock, discarding stuff instead of neatly stowing it saved some time, I imagine. And the reason we don't litter on Earth (or shouldn't) is to avoid poisoning the environment. With no environment except dead rock, that reason is void.

Comment: Apollo 11 left two Hasselblad cameras on the Moon.